# UTC Time to String Conversion

Tags: matlab, datetime, time, utc

I am looking for helping doing time conversions from UTC time to string using MATLAB.

I am trying to extract time from a data file collected at the end of October 2010.
The data file says it is reporting in UTC time and the field is an integer string value in milliseconds that is around 3.02e11. I would like to convert this to a string but am have some trouble.

I figured out that the units are most definitely in milliseconds so I convert this to fractions of days to be compatible with datenum format.

If the data was collected at the end of October (say, October 31, 2010) then I can guess what kind of number I might get. I thought that January 1, 2001 would be a good epoch and calculated what sort of number (in days) I might get:

```
suspectedDate = datenum('October 31, 2010')
suspectedEpoch = datenum('January 1, 2001')

suspectedTimeInDays = suspectedDate - suspectedEpoch
```

Which comes out as *3590*.

However, my actual time, in days, comes out with the following code

```
actualTime = 3.02e11
actualTimeInDays = 3.02e11/1000/24/3600
```

as *3495.4*.

This is troubling as the difference is only 94.6 -- not a full year. This would mean either the documentation for the file is wrong or the epoch is close to April 1-5, 2001:

```
calculatedEpoch = suspectedDate - actualTimeInDays
calculatedEpochStr = datestr(calculatedEpoch)
```

Alternately, if the epoch is January 1, 2001 then the actual date in the file is from the end of July.

```
ifEpochIsJanuaryDate = suspectedEpoch + actualTimeInDays
ifEpochIsJanuaryDateStr = datestr(ifEpochIsJanuaryDate)
```

Is this a known UTC format and can anyone give suggestions on how to get an October date from 3.02e11 magnitude number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix time today is about 13e11, and is measured in ms since 1970.

If your time is ~3e11, then it's probably since year 2000.

```
>> time_unix = 1339116554872; % example time
>> time_reference = datenum('1970', 'yyyy'); 
>> time_matlab = time_reference + time_unix / 8.64e7;
>> time_matlab_string = datestr(time_matlab, 'yyyymmdd HH:MM:SS.FFF')

    time_matlab_string =

    20120608 00:49:14.872
```

Notes:

1) change 1970 into 2000 if your time is since 2000;

2) See the definition of matlab's time.

3) 8.64e7 is number of milliseconds in a day.

4) Matlab does not apply any time-zone shifts, so the result is the same UTC time.

5) Example for backward transformation:

```
>> matlab_time = now;
>> unix_time = round(8.64e7 * (matlab_time - datenum('1970', 'yyyy')))

unix_time =

             1339118367664
```

Comment: I was never able to find a definitive answer so I marked yours as the closest we're going to get.

Comment: @Steve, I guess the best you can do is to ask what does this value represent those who created this data. If it's milliseconds, then you have  3.02e11/8.64e7/365 = 9.5764 years, which doesn't give any clue if the data was really collected at 2010-10-31

Answer (score 2):

You can't just make up your own epoch.  Also `datenum` returns things in days.  So the closeness you got with doing your math was just a coincidence.

Turns out that

```
>> datenum('Jan-1-0000')

ans =

     1
```

and

```
>> datenum('Jan-1-0001')

ans =

   367
```

So Matlab should be returning things in days since Jan. 1, 0000.  (Not a typo)

However, I'd look carefully at this `3.02e11` number and find out exactly what it means.  I'm pretty sure it's not standard Unix UTC, which should be [*seconds* since January 1, 1970](http://www.epochconverter.com/).  It's way too big.  It's close to GMT: Mon, 1 Jan 11540 08:53:20 UTC.

Comment: You are definitely right. I know for sure that the LSB in the number is in milliseconds, so we could divide by 1000 to get seconds. Then it looks like the date is in reference to some time around 2001. The question then is whether a reference to April or a shift of 4 months makes any sense.

Comment: From the math is sounds doubtful that the whole number is milliseconds.  Maybe it's worth investigating the meaning of this number a little more.  I think this April thing is a coincidence and wild goose chase.